# How to access and display DICOM files on iPhone

Tags: iphone, image-processing, dicom

I would like to develop iPhone application about image processing,access and display DICOM files on screen like [OsiriX](http://itunes.apple.com/app/id419227089?mt=8).But i don't know what libraries to do that.

I don't know OsiriX have library or plugin for developer.Do you know ??
(Sorry foe my bad english.)

Advice me,Please

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DCMTK](http://dicom.offis.de/dcmtk.php.en) works fine on IOS

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to consider Monotouch, a possibility would be DICOM# - http://sourceforge.net/projects/dicom-cs/

Comment: Thank you for answer.But iPhone application use Objective-C develop not C#.

Comment: @miniplayground, with Mono, you can compile c# codes in obj-c environment.

Comment: @Gary Tsui,Really!! Sorry I don't know. :)

Answer (score 0):

[idoimaging.com](http://idoimaging.com) lists a number of DICOM-compatible libraries. I'd start with that list and see if one or more of those could easily be ported to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

the easier ways would be to locate c/c++ dicom library (since you only need the lib to extract the tag-value pairs and the pixel data).  And, link your development(i assume that'd be a viewer) to that c/c++ library.   Note that, for j2k compression, you probably need a more advanced dicom library if not another img lib that supports j2k.

FYR (DICOM in C/C++)
[1] http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/
[2] http://imebra.com/

Answer (score 0):

[Imebra](https://imebra.com) is written in C++ but it includes Objective-C helpers that allow to build directly UIImage or NSImage objects from loaded datasets.

You have to rename your source file with a .mm extension (instead of .m) so they can use C++ features.

Here is a small sample that load a Dicom file then get the image as UIImage (without applying the presentation VOI/LUT for simplicity):

```
using namespace puntoexe;

// Open the file test.dcm for reading
ptr<stream> readStream(new stream);
readStream->openFile(NSStringToStringW(@"test.dcm"), std::ios::in);
ptr<streamReader> reader(new streamReader(readStream));

// Parse the file into a dataSet structure
ptr<imebra::dataSet> testDataSet = 
        imebra::codecs::codecFactory::getCodecFactory()->load(reader);

// Get the patient name
NSString* patientNameCharacter = StringWToNSString(testDataSet->getString(0x0010, 0, 0x0010, 0));

// Get the first image
ptr<imebra::image> firstImage = testDataSet->getModalityImage(0);
UIImage* myUIImage = getImage(firstImage, 0);
```